# Python SOAP client with Zeep - accessing password protected wsdl

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to create a python soap client with zeep but run into some problem when trying to access the wsdl. No matter how many existing solutions on the web I have tried, none of them is working anymore, or just my case is a little bit different. Most promising is the solution in the official zeep docs, but it still does not quite work:

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)
client = Client('https://url/to/my_wsdl.wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))
```

But I get an error:

```
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\client.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.wsdl = Document(wsdl, self.transport, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 82, in __init__
    root_definitions.resolve_imports()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 234, in resolve_imports
    binding.resolve(self)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 128, in resolve
    operation.resolve(definitions)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 428, in resolve
    self.output.resolve(definitions, self.abstract.output_message)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 285, in resolve
    self.body = self._resolve_body(info['body'], definitions, parts)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 423, in _resolve_body
    element = part.element.clone()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I am using python3.6 32bit on windows 10. All packages were freshly installed using pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there is no solution to this problem for now. Maybe in future Zeep releases this bug will be fixed.

However I've found a workaround. Instead of Zeep use SUDS (or suds-py3 for python3.x). Creating client from wsdl with user and password requirements is even simpler here. Just use:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client(url=WSDL_URL,
                username=WSDL_USERNAME,
                password=WSDL_PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 1):

author of zeep here. Seems like you hit a bug in Zeep. Can you submit an issue as documented at http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/reporting_bugs.html to https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues ?

I'll look at it asap then.